# How to get rid of SettingWithCopyWarning for the assignment operator in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, warnings

I  have itemid as a column in a dataset. I want to access a complete row based on a particular itemid. 
`v[i]`  contains itemid.

So I have written the below code which works with a warning,

```
for k,v  in dataframeItemList.items():
   length = len(v) 
   for i in range(length):
        myDf = dataset.loc[dataset['itemid'] == v[i]]
```

warning is:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value
```

How do I change this line `myDf = dataset.loc[dataset['itemid'] == v[i]]` to get rid of this warning ?

Comment: Try this `myDf = dataset.loc[dataset['itemid'] == v[i]].copy()`

Comment: @manojk Great! thank you so much :)